# (Databricks-Spark) How to work around the issue of using secret-scopes to protect login information resulting in Spark dataframe to also be redacted?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have a secret-scope registered into our Databricks account which details login parameters.

```
secret_scope = "My-Secret"
params = ["user", "password"]
conn_params = {param: dbutils.secrets.get(scope=secret, key=param) for param in params}
```

The resulting output from a print of conn_params is:

> {'user': '[REDACTED]', 'password': '[REDACTED]'}

Which is all good and dandy. If I use `conn_params` to instantiate a connection to a library which allows me to retrieve info from a data source (like a RDBMS, etc.) the connection works fine.

But the issue comes when I use this connection info to create a Spark DataFrame.
The resulting DataFrame also has all its data redacted, which makes it unusable.

```
# Something like...
with someConn(**conn_params) as conn:
     # do something 
...

result = df
df.show()
```

If I do not use secret-scopes, and literally declare:

```
conn_params = {'user': 'me', 'password': 'pw'}
```

And use the literal key:value pairs, I result in a non-redacted and usable DataFrame.

Any way to work around on this? The official docs on this are astonishingly weak. 
[databricks official docs](https://docs.databricks.com/security/secrets/redaction.html)

*p.s: Using Pyspark for now, but if things only work on Scala for Databricks, welcome those soultions as well*

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out the only thing redacted is the output (like print(), show(), display()) for the **spark session** where the secret-scope was called.

If I save to table it is fine, and in new or other spark sessions, as long as you have access, it is usable.

A bit of a pain if you are trying to look at your work as you program, but for PRD purposes, it seems to work fine.

Still wish the docs were a bit clear on this. I had to get this from some tech blog post written by Databricks a while back when they first introduced secret-scopes.

**Step it up Databricks**